# Returning specific instances from generic function

Tags: generics, kotlin

My question is about type inference with generic methods.

I've got the following scenario:

```
interface Obj {
    val Id: String
}
data class User(override val Id: String, val name: String): Obj
data class Case(override val Id: String, val subject: String): Obj

interface Api {
    fun <T: Obj> getLastUpdated(type: KClass<T>, backTill: Duration = Duration.ofDays(1)): LastUpdated

    fun <T: Obj> getDetails(type: KClass<T>, uuid: String): Details<T>

    data class LastUpdatedResponse(val ids: List<String> = emptyList(),
                                   val latestDateCovered: String = "")
    data class LastUpdated(val error: Throwable? = null, val response: LastUpdatedResponse? = null)

    data class DetailsResponse<T>(val wrapped: T)
    data class Details<T>(val error: Throwable? = null, val response: DetailsResponse<T>? = null)
}
```

In my tests, I need to know exactly what the mocked API needs to return, thus

```
val testCase = Case("123", "Testing")
val testUser = User("321", "Dummy")
val mockApi = object: Api {
    override fun <T : Obj> getLastUpdated(type: KClass<T>, backTill: Duration): Api.LastUpdated {
        return Api.LastUpdated(response = Api.LastUpdatedResponse(listOf("123")))
    }

    override fun <T : Obj> getDetails(type: KClass<T>, uuid: String): Details<T> {
        when (type) {
            Case::class -> return Api.Details(response = Api.DetailsResponse(wrapped = testCase)) // <- this fails
            User::class -> return Api.Details(response = Api.DetailsResponse(wrapped = testUser)) // <- as does this
            else -> return Api.Details(error = UnsupportedOperationException())
        }
    }
}
```

However, this fails to compile with:

```
Error:(114, 43) Kotlin: Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Api.Details<Case> but Api.Details<T> was expected
```

I can make it work with casting:

```
when (type) {
    Case::class -> return Api.Details(response = Api.DetailsResponse(wrapped = testCase)) as Api.Details<T>
    User::class -> return Api.Details(response = Api.DetailsResponse(wrapped = testUser)) as Api.Details<T>
```

But then I get a warning informing me that "this cast will never succeed" - running my tests, it does and works as expected.

My question is - why doesn't this work without casting and what should I use instead?

Comment: on what line do you get the exception? Please mark it with a comment

Comment: @voddan Totally forgot it wasn't obvious from the "works with casting" lines. Marked, unfortunately the lines are quite long.

Comment: Why do you use kClass? I think it is not a good idea to use that class if you want to use extension of classes/interfaces. Why not this:
```kotlin
 fun <T: Obj> getDetails(obj :Obj, uuid: String): Details<out T>{

   when(obj){
     is User ->  -> return Api.Details<User>(response = Api.DetailsResponse(wrapped = obj))
     is Case -> ...
}
```

Comment: @jorgemf: the full signature is `fun <T: Obj> getDetails(type: KClass<T>, uuid: String, fields: List<String> = type.members.map { it.name})`, other than that, I only use `type` to signal the deserialization target to jackson.

Comment: @mabi Based on @x2bool solution and conversation. I think what you want to do is impossible, you cannot defined a function which sometimes returns a Details<User> and others Details<Case>, it is going to return always Details<Obj>. So you are going to need a cast. One thing you can do is to add the output value of the function as an input element. ```fun <T: Obj> getDetails( type: kClass<T>, uuid: String, ..., output: Details<T>)``` and then call the function with the concrete details class you want and only add the object in details: ```getDetails(Case::kClass, Api.Details<Case>())```

Comment: @jorgemf I don't get it - the generic version I posted *works* and returns a completely typed instance each call. I get that flow analysis is hard and maybe too much for the compiler to work out I'm always returning the promised type. But I'm still wondering why the compiler warns me that "this cast will never succeed"?

Comment: Using in and out solves your problem, read my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Variance annotation might help you, just change generic parameter **T** to **out Obj** in the following function (in both interface and implementer class):

```
fun <T: Obj> getDetails(type: KClass<T>, uuid: String): Details<out Obj>
```

Comment: That certainly gets me rid of the cast, very good! But now I reduce every return value to `Obj` ie, I won't be able to access `Case.subject` w/o a cast.

Comment: Then you can't do that. You're trying to return two specific types from a generic function. You have to specify the lower bounds.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem:

```
    override fun getDetails(type: KClass<in Obj>, uuid: String): Api.Details<out Obj> {
        when (type) {
            Case::class -> return Api.Details(response = Api.DetailsResponse(wrapped = testCase))
            User::class -> return Api.Details(response = Api.DetailsResponse(wrapped = testUser))
            else -> return Api.Details(error = UnsupportedOperationException())
        }
    }
```

In order to understand it better you can read the kotlin documentation about variance in generics: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

There are things you cannot do in java as:

```
Collection<String> strings = ...
Collection<Object> objs = strings; // this will fail
```

There are a lot of cases when you only want to read the generics objects so there is no problem to make that assignment. The way to tell kotlin this is possible is using the words in and out. In means you are going to read the generics but not write them and out mean you are going to write them.